# SpamAssassin считает что у меня не настроен rDNS

Tags: email, dkim, spamassasin, spf

Когда настраивал почту то проверил качество своих писем через [mail-tester.com](http://www.mail-tester.com/)

Оценка была 10 из 10.

На днях подключил cloudflare. IP адрес для web изменился. Но письма то уходят с IP реального. Оценка упала до `8.8`.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

`DKIM`, `dmarc`, `SPF`, `rDNS` все настроено. Что и показывает `dig`

```
$ dig -x 93.189.40.239 +short
yezzo.me.
```

Нашел похожий вопрос на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297861/spamassassin-rdns-reversedns).
Вот вывод dig

```
    $ dig -x 93.189.40.239 A

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> -x 93.189.40.239 A
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;239.40.189.93.in-addr.arpa.    IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
40.189.93.in-addr.arpa. 1794    IN  SOA msk-ns1.nt-com.ru. ncc.nt-com.ru. 1504131535 14400 3600 1728000 3600

;; Query time: 241 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 13 15:35:47 FET 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 112
```

Здесь уже я имени домена своего не вижу, значит нужно прописать что-то в DNS. Но не пойму что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял, почта отсылается с машины, имеющей ip-адрес 93.189.40.239.

можно поступить, например, так:

1. изменить rdns: вместо yezzo.me резолвить ip-адрес 93.189.40.239 в, например, mail.yezzo.me.
2. добавить соответствующую запись в домене yezzo.me:

mail IN A 93.189.40.239

Comment: Да, мне также в оффлайне посоветовали.